# jQuery function and jQuery object it's applied on

Tags: jquery

this is kind of a global question :

When you create a custom jQuery function using `$.fn.foo = function(){}`
and let's say we apply this function to `$("#foo")` just like `$("#foo").foo()`:

How can we refer to `$("#foo")` in the function independently from its "absolute name" ?

I tried using `$(this)` but the console spew an error at me :
`Ignoring get or set of property that has [LenientThis] because the "this" object is incorrect.`

Comment: And did you simply try `this`?

Comment: Indeed using `this` solved my problem thx !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jquery site has a good starting point for creating plug-ins: ["How to Create a Basic Plugin"](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/). It mentions:

> ... we use `this`, not `$( this )` ...

In the section [Using the `each` method](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/#using-the-each-method), you'll find a common pattern:

> Your typical jQuery object will contain references to any number of DOM elements, and that's why jQuery objects are often referred to as collections. If you want to do any manipulating with specific elements (e.g. getting a data attribute, calculating specific positions) then you need to use `.each()` to loop through the elements.
>
> ```
> $.fn.myNewPlugin = function() { 
>
>    return this.each(function() {
>        // Do something to each element here.
>    });
>
> };
> ```